# Get The file from Asset Folder android

Tags: android, file, assets

i use this code to get the file from asset folder:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/"+knowImage))
```

but when print this line always get space between the file:///android_asset and string from knowimage!

when  print knowimage there is no space! but when they combine result is with a space and so  can not use it

output is so :

```
11-23 14:16:29.128: I/Share(18204): file:///android_asset/
11-23 14:16:29.128: I/Share(18204): lovingurpregnantbodyS.png
```

but it must be like this :

```
file:///android_asset/lovingurpregnantbodyS.png
```

Comment: How do you produce the output you specified? Is it Uri.toString or something else?

Answer (score 4):

This is the method you can use as per your requirement in Application. You can also re-size Images while you display on ImageView. Hop this will help you.

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String strName) {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        InputStream istr = null;
        try {
            try {
                istr = assetManager.open(strName);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                istr = assetManager.open("noimage.png");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
        int Height = bitmap.getHeight();
        int Width = bitmap.getWidth();
        float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int dip = (int) (40 * scale + 0.5f);
        int newHeight = width - dip;
        int newWidth = width - dip;
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / Width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / Height;
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, Width, Height,
                matrix, true);

        return resizedBitmap;
    }
```

> **Call method like:**

```
Imgview.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromAsset("YourFoldername/"+ imgname + ".jpg"));
```

Comment: I removed all resizing things and set Bitmap bitmap2=Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap) , and use getBitmapFromAsset(xxxx.png) , but it crashes!

Comment: now i can get the image but when it comes to Other application it crashes , means when image is passing to Gmail or whatever it crashes! GMAIL CRASHES or WHATSAPP CRASHES , seems they can not open the bitmap or what

Answer (score 2):

You can use this method:

```
public static void loadAssetImage(String path, ImageView imageView,
        Context context)
{
    try
    {
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getAssets().open(path));
        imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, b.getHeight(),
                b.getHeight() * b.getHeight() / b.getWidth(), false));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Exception", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

Call in Activity:

```
FileUtils.loadAssetImage("Folder/image.png, imageView, CurrentActivity.this);
```